# ¿Cómo llenar vector de forma recursiva en C?

Tags: c

Tengo que hacer una función recursiva que inicialice un vector con un valor recibido por parámetro de la función.
Entiendo que para hacerlo de forma iterativa sería así:

```
void leer_arreglo(int a[], int n){    
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++){               
       printf ("Ingrese elemento:\n");
    scanf ("%d", &a[i]);
    }
}
```

Ahora, para hacerlo de forma recursiva no me sale bien. He puesto algo más o menos así:

```
#define TAM 10

void inicializar_arreglo (int a[], int n){
   if (a[TAM]=a[n])
      return 0;
   else
      inicializar_arreglo(a[i-1]);
}
```

Comment: cual es el objetivo de hacerlo recursivo solo consumes mas memoria...

Comment: Es cierto, pero es lo que pide la letra del ejercicio...

Comment: ya te puse una respuesta revisala que funciona perfectamente

Comment: siempre ten en cuenta que praa las funciones recursivas debes definir la parada de la recursividad y void no acepta return 0; pues es void o sea vacio seria return;

Comment: Ah sería solo return. El arreglo y número son variables globales?

Comment: si son globales pero para mayor comodidad y legibilidad del codigo

Comment: si esta solucion te resolvio el problema marcala como aceptada en la palomita si no es molestia me ayudarias mucho @Adri

Comment: gracias cualqier duda que tenga me dices

Comment: Gracias Alex, funciona perfecto. No me queda claro qué hace esto:
arrayt[tam] = numero;
    iniciar_arreglo(tam+1);

Comment: Ah, inicializas el tam en 1 en el main para que cuente hasta 10. Me queda claro. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aqui tienes la solucuion

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int arrayt[10];
int numero;

void iniciar_arreglo(int tam)
{
if(tam == 10)
    return;
else{
    cin >> numero;
    arrayt[tam] = numero;
    iniciar_arreglo(tam+1);
}
}

int main()
{
iniciar_arreglo(1);

for(int i = 1; i <= 9; i++)
    cout << arrayt[i] << ' ';

return 0;
}
```

Comment: espero que te sirva

Comment: me dices cualqier duda